# Error al ejecutar 'rails s'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Al momento de querer levantar el servicio del server me da esto:

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
/home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
     ... 4044 levels...
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/ricardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: tienes alguna conversion dentro de la aplicación ?

Answer (score 0):

Revisando [la solución en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41504382/895789), sale que tus opciones son:

- Hacer un downgrade de ruby a una versión anterior a 2.4 (estás usando ruby 2.4.1)
- O actualizar rails a la versión 4.2.8 o posterior (estás usando rails 4.2.6)